# iOS Is there a way to keep the UISearchBar in TableviewHeader when active

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

In a current app I'm creating I want to know if there is a way to prevent the UISearchController searchbar moving into the UInavigationbar when its active. I've added it to the tableview tableHeadeView but I want to keep it there instead of it becoming the UInvagiationbar when active. Basically I want to keep from hiding the UInavigationController navbar when the search is active. How can I accomplish this?

I've already tried adding this code to the searchController delegate method for updating text and it didn't work:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Current code:

```
friendsSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
friendsSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
friendsSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
friendsSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

friendsSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
friendsSearchController.searchBar.placeholder =  @"Find friends";
[friendsSearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = friendsSearchController.searchBar;
```

Comment: set `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` property of `UISearchController` to NO

Comment: This works but for some reason the searchController searchable drops down about 50 pixels from its original position, do you know why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: try removing `UISearchBarStyleMinimal` once, but I am not exactly sure about that.

Comment: I ended up reseting the frame in the searchBarShouldBeginEditing delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` property of `UISearchController` determines whether the navigation bar is hidden during searching. Set it to `NO`

```
friendsSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```